# OrientDB - Homebrew install - how to use OSystem database in test

Tags: ruby, homebrew, orientdb

I'm trying to update the homebrew formula for OrientDB 2.2.2.  Since 2.2.0 (note that a working homebrew formula for 2.2.0 was never created), OrientDB now creates a system database, OSystem.

The problem is, when testing the homebrew formula, OrientDB is not allowed to write outside of homebrew's test path.  When OrientDB starts, it tries to do this to create the OSystem database and the build fails.

The open PR is at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/2004.

I don't know much about ruby, orientDb, or homebrew internals, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker. There are some built images so that you don't have to install dependencies yourself.

To run the image, run:

```
docker run --name orientdb -d -v <config_path>:/opt/orientdb/config -v <databases_path>:/opt/orientdb/databases -v <backup_path>:/opt/orientdb/backup -p 2424 -p 2480 nesrait/orientdb-2.0
```

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/#installation
- http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-docker.wiki/Home.html

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I'm trying to get the homebrew installation working.